# Can't access QML item by id inside SplitView

Tags: qt, qml

I've began learning QML and I'm getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: chatTextArea is not defined

I have a global function that does something on an item within the same QML file, by id.

For some reason I can't access via the ID of my TextArea, or any item inside of the SplitView. But I am able to manipulate the properties of TabView and each Tab.

My broken code:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
id: lobby

function appendChatMsg(msg) {
    chatTextArea.append(msg) //causes: ReferenceError: chatTextArea is not defined
}

TabView {
    id: frame

    Tab { //I CAN access this item via ID.
        id: controlPage

        SplitView {
            anchors.fill: parent

            TableView {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }

            GridLayout {
                columns: 1

                TextArea { //This item I CANNOT access via ID.
                    id: chatTextArea

                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }

                TextField {
                    placeholderText: "Type something..."
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any idea why chatTextArea is out of scope of my function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Change the starting portion of your code to smth like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
id: lobby

function appendChatMsg(msg) {
    controlPage.chatArea.append(msg) //causes: ReferenceError: chatTextArea is not defined
}

TabView {
    id: frame

    Tab { //I CAN access this item via ID.
        id: controlPage
        property Item chatArea: item.chatArea

        SplitView {
            property Item chatArea: chatTextArea
```

Reason this works, is that `Tab` turns out to behave like a Loader (per the docs), loading whichever **Component** you give it; thus, the `SplitView` in your code is a Component specification, and that component is instantiated by the `Tab` in a separate QML context (parented to that of the document root item). Which is why everything inside that context can see things up the scope chain (like the `appendMessage()` function), but not the reverse :)

Comment: Thanks! This removed the error. 

However I'm still having difficulty. I'm trying to respond to a signal that is in the 'main' QML file. My Lobby gets dynamically loaded into main.qml via a Loader. How can I trigger my function inside Lobby.qml when a signal in main.qml is fired?

Comment: You can reach main by id through the scope chain, and connect to its signal via `signalName.connect()`, I think (probably, in the Lobby's `onCompleted()`).